# createObjectURL: Type Error in Safari when using Blob

Tags: javascript, webrtc, blob, video.js, createobjecturl

In HTML `<video>` object, I cannot play a video recorded by the *video.js-record* library. I checked the Blob returned in the `player.recordedData` variable and wanted to assign it to the object like mentioned in the example from the Documentation:

```
recordedVideo.src = createObjURL(this.player.recordedData);
```

It fails with an error on this specific line:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Type error

--

(I am already checking the use of `URL` vs `webkitURL` using this function:

```
function createObjURL ( file ) {
    if ( window.webkitURL ) {
        return window.webkitURL.createObjectURL( file );
    } else if ( window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL ) {
        return window.URL.createObjectURL( file );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and it seems to use the right version.)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the document of video.js-record, `player.recordedData` is not a Blob (what you would need to pass to `createObjectUrl`) but an array of blob segments - this would match the `TypeError`.

The following change should help:

```
function createObjURL ( blobPieces ) {
    var blob = new Blob(blobPieces, { type: 'video/webm' });
    if ( window.webkitURL ) {
        return window.webkitURL.createObjectURL( blob );
    } else if ( window.URL && window.URL.createObjectURL ) {
        return window.URL.createObjectURL( blob );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not help. `player.recordedData` already returns a Blob. This would be its console.log:
`Blob { lastModified: 1580220847318, lastModifiedDate: Date Tue Jan 28 2020 15:14:07 GMT+0100, name: "1580220847318.webm", size: 362155, type: "video/webm" }`