# Show a video recorded in WebRTC in video object in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc

When using WebRTC to record a video directly from user webcam, you get a BLOB object with the video.

```
video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

When trying to apply the blob to the video element (for example with the code above or other alternatives like webkitURL, etc... as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934597/311188), it fails in Safari.

It shows the video controls, but it shows 0 seconds, and play does nothing.

Somebody created an example to achieve this, but it uses File (https://bl.ocks.org/unRob/3bd07a012597aa959c92) and File is not allowed in Safari

And I have been searching for how to create a File in Safari, but it does not work.

How can I put a blob directly in a video element so user can PLAY and PREVIEW what he has just recorded ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333767/html5-video-streaming-video-with-blob-urls this might help

Comment: Not working ... mediaSource.addSourceBuffer returns error in Safari (Not SupportedError: The operation is not supported"

Comment: Are you using Safari for MacOS or iOS?

Comment: Both of them should be work. But I'm starting with iOS (iPhone 12)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebRTC, I assume that you are getting the content doing something like this:

```
const mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
```

In that case, you just simply need to attach that stream to your video element doing:

`video.srcObject = mediaStream`

Comment: That's working in Chrome and Firefox with no problems at all ... that's theory ... but iOS / Safari are in other universe ... that does not work at all, but thank you ;-)

Comment: That's weird, I understand what you are saying, but I got that working on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. 
Have you added the [webrtc-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-adapter)?
You can check the functionality [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/)

Comment: Record a video, and then put the video blob recorded in the player ... you'll see in Safari does not work

Answer (score 0):

demo videojs work on safari，this is demo & codepen link

```
player.el_.querySelector('video').src = null;
player.el_.querySelector('video').srcObject = stream;
player.play();
```

https://codepen.io/yuchichang/pen/gOqRjLB